# Error: XmlException was unhandled by user code

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xml-parsing, xmldocument

I have an error like: "An exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in System.Xml.dll but was not handled in user code"

In my program, i use a service reference from this site: http://www.oorsprong.org/websamples.countryinfo/CountryInfoService.wso and when running the program, it stops me to the string.

**The XML file:** (I want to take only the sName)

```
<ArrayOftContinent>
    <tContinent>
        <sCode>AF</sCode>
        <sName>Africa</sName>
    </tContinent>
</ArrayOftContinent>
```

Here is the code:

```
org.oorsprong.www.CountryInfoService myWS3 = new org.oorsprong.www.CountryInfoService();
string str = Convert.ToString(myWS3.ListOfContinentsByName());
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(str); /*It stops me here*/
```

Could you help me how to handle this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, what does the string in `str` look like?

Comment: str is an XML String which will hold all the continents in xml format @LasseVågsætherKarlsen

Comment: @Christina Please copy the actual xml text in that string, and paste it into your question, so we can see it and test your code with it.

Comment: You say that it is an xml string, but apparently `XmlDocument` disagrees, you would need to paste your XML or produce a [mcve] for us to try.

Comment: Is that xml the content of `str`? You **verified** this? What I'm suspecting is that you're actually getting a list of some object from that client you have declared there and that your `ToString` method converts this to something like `"System.Collections.Generic.List'1[org.oorsprong.www.Country]"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your wso is returning continent objects, not an xml string.  Read the definition:
http://www.oorsprong.org/websamples.countryinfo/CountryInfoService.wso?op=ListOfContinentsByName

You want to do something like this:

```
org.oorsprong.www.CountryInfoService myWS3 = new org.oorsprong.www.CountryInfoService();
var continents = myWS3.ListOfContinentsByName();

foreach (var continent in continents)
       Debug.WriteLine(continent.sName)
```